# Re-initialise livedata object

Tags: android, android-livedata

Is it possible to have a live data property just reinitialize with the value it was set with?

for example in the ViewModel we have...

```
val apiKey = MutableLiveData<String>().apply {
    value = context.apiKey
}
```

say context gets the API Key from shared prefs

Now let's say that context.apikey has been updated

Right now the only way for me to observe this change on my activity is
`viewModel.apiKey.postValue(this.apiKey)`

Is there a better way of doing this? Would be nice to have something like...
viewModel.apiKey.reset() ... or something?

Comment: simply extend `LiveData` class and add `reset()` method

Comment: Thanks @pskink , thats correct and should be the excepted answer.